# Viscous fluids not working as intended

Tags: mantaflow

I have an animation where a character is sinking into a viscous liquid (simulated with Mantaflow), but the liquid isn't acting as I want it to. I want the liquid to deform concavely around the character. This picture here is a good example of what I'm talking about; notice how the tar around her foot makes a concave shape around it as it sinks in.

[image]

In my project, the liquid is doing the opposite; its deforming convexly around the character, almost as if the liquid is crawling up it. You can see this clearly in this picture from my project:

[image]

Is there any way to get the liquid to deform the way I want?

Comment: do you mean something like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hbnY.gif

Comment: Yeah exactly like that! How did you do that?

Comment: Use viscosity and increase it

Comment: Could you screenshot your fluid settings? That's what I was doing before and it wasn't really working